# Range queries for strings

Tags: c, data-structures

My order is defined as 'A < a < B < b ...< Z < z'.
I have to find if a given string is in range or not.
Ex. If my range is AaA - BaB, AA or AaaB is inthe range, but not CbAA.

I am looking for any pointers, ideas, suggestions to help me start. I will implement this in C.

Comment: Do you have a prototype for the function?  An outline of even a potential algorithm?  Or are you asking us to even do the basics for you?

Comment: A pointer: `(void *)0x7f54ba00`

Comment: I am trying to figure out what data structures I should use, fenwick tree? IT somehow seems too complicated, there has to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

So all you need to implement is a single function that compares two strings according to your rules. It is kind of modified lexicograogical sorting:

```
int compare_letters(char x, char y) {
  char lx = tolower(x);
  char ly = tolower(y);
  if (lx != ly) {
    return lx < ly;
  } else {
    return x < y;
  }
}
int smaller(const char* a, const char* b) {
  .. use the above function ... 
}
```

Now make use of the above function and to check if a given string x is in the range (a,b), check if `smaller(a, x)` and `smaller(x, b)`. That's it.

Some tips on the function smaller - compare the strings char by char and if the two chars differ, return their `compare_letter`. If one of the strings runs out of letters, consider it smaller.

Comment: Would it be better to return the tristate (-1, 0, +1) value that functions such as `strcmp()` return (strictly, `<0`, `0`, `>0`) and that functions such as `qsort()` and `bsearch()` expect to use?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe a `smaller than` operator would suffice here. Maybe its because I am more used to `c++` but that's the way I write such things. Of course what you propose is absolutely doable and maybe a little bit more 'c-ish' :)

Comment: Standard C++ does things with operators like the one you showed (and I wondered if I was detecting a C++ background).  It's workable in C, but functions such as `qsort()` and `bsearch()` have different requirements from C++, and ... you're right that it is easily fixed to suit the actual requirements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well I have not tried to write the code in a way that it would work with qsort after all the task is simply to check if a number is in a given range. Otherwise of course I need how to implement a comparison operator for qsort.